# Returning a value from anon function within jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I have a function that forces a user to log in if they click submit and it finds they aren't logged in:

```
$('#buildFormQueue').submit(function(){
    return $.dialogs.forceLogin();
});
```

I need `forceLogin()` to return true if the user login has succeeded.. the problem, however, is that the login form is loaded by ajax and the `forceLogin()` function is finished executing before the user even sees the login dialog.

```
forceLogin : function(){
    if(!$.loggedIn){
        $.ajax('/index.php?act=loginDialog', {success:function(data){
            $("#dialog-message").html(data)
            .attr('title', 'Please Log In')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'Log In': function(){
                        $this = $(this);
                        $.post('/index.php?act=loginDialog&mode=post', {
                            'username'  : $("#dialog-message :input[name='username']").val(),
                            'password'  : $("#dialog-message :input[name='password']").val()
                        }, function(data){
                            if(data == "true"){
                                $this.dialog('close');
                                $.loggedIn = true;
                            }else{
                                $this.find('div').slideDown('slow');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                },
                width: 400,
                position: ['center', 50],
            });
            $('#dialog-message :input').keypress(function (e) {
                if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonset :last').click();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }});
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
},
```

Is there any way of `forceLogin()` to return from within the `'Log In': function()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to do this because the `forceLogin` function will complete synchronously while the ajax request will complete asynchronously.

The standard way of working around this though is to have `forceLogin` return nothing and instead take in a callback function to which the result of the login will later be passed.  For example

```
forceLogin : function(callback) { 
  ...
  $.post(..., function(data) {
    if (data === 'true') {
      callback(true);
    } else {
      callback(false);
    }
  });
  ...
});
```

The calling code then just needs to move it's handling logic into a lambda.

Old Way:

```
if (forceLogin()) {
  succeededAction();
} else {
  failedAction();
}
```

New Way:

```
forceLogin(function(succeeded) {
  if (succeeded) {
    succeededAction();
  } else {
    failedAction();
  }
});
```

Comment: That's actually much simpler and elegant than I had expected. Problem is though, that just moved the issue to a different place. The callback function passed to `$('#buildFormQueue').submit()` needs to return true to allow the form to be submitted - but if I call `forceLogin()` inside of `submit()`, the argument passed to that callback needs to find it's way up a level to return in the `submit()` function.

Comment: @kavisiegel can you intercept the submit the first time, prevent it, and then re-submit once the login completes succesfully?

Comment: Ah, now that's one I should have thought of! Thanks, I ended up just changing it to `return $.dialogs.forceLogin(function(){$form.submit()});` and adding in a callback() call when the login in successful. Thanks a ton!